# how to change letters in list without moving other argument - python3

Tags: python-3.x, lowercase

[sublime screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbybG.png)

hi,
I am a rookie who have just started learning python3.
In a practice where we try to change the letters from upper cases to lower cases, I tried to do so without removing numbers. but the function 'lower()' is not working as illustrated in the screenshot.

Any one knows why?
appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Provide some code.

Comment: hi, I posted a screenshot. But looks like the people here are more used to code. I will use code next time. and I received some answers from other people. Thanks a lot for reaching out.

Comment: @郭上阳  If it satifies with your solutoin then you should accept the answer and upvote it so that people can find correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, whatever you change in s(lower case) you are not effecting the change in p. P is still the same old string and hasnt changed.
try p = [] and p.append(s.lower())

Also dont post screenshots, they are difficult. Would much rather prefer your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one liner:

---

```
#Code:
l = ["HEllo", "World", 123]
x = map(lambda item: item.lower() if isinstance(item, str) is True else item, l)
print(x)
```

---

```
#output:
['hello', 'world', 123]
```